# What is Pc Materialization?

Tags: c++, c, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

I am working with a tool called for binary instrumentation called [Intel Pin](http://pintool.org/). However I encountered this strange terminology while I was examining part of the examples that Pin comes with. Here is the relevant part:

```
VOID CallTrace(TRACE trace, INS ins)
{
    if (!KnobTraceCalls)
        return;

    if (INS_IsCall(ins) && !INS_IsDirectBranchOrCall(ins))
    {
        // Indirect call
        string s = "Call " + FormatAddress(INS_Address(ins), TRACE_Rtn(trace));
        s += " -> ";

        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, AFUNPTR(EmitIndirectCall), IARG_THREAD_ID,
                       IARG_PTR, new string(s), IARG_BRANCH_TARGET_ADDR,
                       IARG_G_ARG0_CALLER, IARG_G_ARG1_CALLER, IARG_END);
    }
    else if (INS_IsDirectBranchOrCall(ins))
    {
        // Is this a tail call?
        RTN sourceRtn = TRACE_Rtn(trace);
        RTN destRtn = RTN_FindByAddress(INS_DirectBranchOrCallTargetAddress(ins));

        if (INS_IsCall(ins)         // conventional call
            || sourceRtn != destRtn // tail call
        )
        {
            BOOL tailcall = !INS_IsCall(ins);

            string s = "";
            if (tailcall)
            {
                s += "Tailcall ";
            }
            else
            {
                if( INS_IsProcedureCall(ins) )
                    s += "Call ";
                else
                {
                    s += "PcMaterialization ";
                    tailcall=1;
                }

            }

            //s += INS_Mnemonic(ins) + " ";

            s += FormatAddress(INS_Address(ins), TRACE_Rtn(trace));
            s += " -> ";

            ADDRINT target = INS_DirectBranchOrCallTargetAddress(ins);

            s += FormatAddress(target, RTN_FindByAddress(target));

            INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, AFUNPTR(EmitDirectCall),
                           IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_PTR, new string(s), IARG_BOOL, tailcall,
                           IARG_G_ARG0_CALLER, IARG_G_ARG1_CALLER, IARG_END);
        }
    }
    else if (INS_IsRet(ins))
    {
        RTN rtn =  TRACE_Rtn(trace);

#if defined(TARGET_LINUX) && defined(TARGET_IA32)
//        if( RTN_Name(rtn) ==  "_dl_debug_state") return;
        if( RTN_Valid(rtn) && RTN_Name(rtn) ==  "_dl_runtime_resolve") return;
#endif
        string tracestring = "Return " + FormatAddress(INS_Address(ins), rtn);
        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, AFUNPTR(EmitReturn),
                       IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_PTR, new string(tracestring), IARG_G_RESULT0, IARG_END);
    }
}
```

This method determines what actually is the instruction doing (direct call, indirect call, tail call, return and the unknown Pc Materialization).

Here is the [full code](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/performance/Gwalp/gwalpsite/pin/source/tools/DebugTrace/debugtrace.cpp).

So what does it mean at all? I tried googling - no relevant results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOOL LEVEL_CORE::INS_IsPcMaterialization    (   INS     ins  )

Returns:
true if this is a call to the next instruction, which is an idiom for materializing the instruction pointer

[Check it](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__IA32.html)

Comment: Can't believe I missed it ... only I know how stupid I feel now :D Thanks!